# Merge rows with multiple data class

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr, tidyverse

I am trying to *amalgamate* two rows together so that the output is best of both worlds. I have read through some of the solutions using `ddply` or `aggregate`, however they work only with numeric data.

Below is an example of what I am trying to do.

**Input:**

```
x <- c("Yemen", 1, NA, NA, 4, 5, "Six")
y <- c("Yemen", NA, "B", 3, NA, 6, "Six")

DF <- as.data.frame(rbind(x,y))
colnames(DF)[1] <- c("CNTRY")
```

**Output**

```
"Yemen", 1, "B", 3, 4, 5, "Six"
```

where the key is `CNTRY`

Ideally, I should be able to choose whether to retain value of `x` or `y` if they are different.

---

**Edit 1:**

The solution should work on a data frame `DF` in this example and not `x` & `y`. My data frame has multiple accounts which are duplicated and I am trying to merge all of the rows that have more than one instance but share the account (key).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using fill from tidyr package:

```
# dummy data with 2 countries to group on
x <- c("Yemen", 1, NA, NA, 4, 5, "Six")
y <- c("Yemen", NA, "B", 3, NA, 6, "Six")
xx <- c("XXX", 3, NA, 33, 4, 7, "Four")
yy <- c("XXX", 2, "B", NA, NA, NA, NA)
DF <- as.data.frame(rbind(x,y,xx,yy))
colnames(DF)[1] <- c("CNTRY")

# using tidyr fill function up and down
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>% group_by(CNTRY) %>% 
  fill_(colnames(DF), .direction = "down") %>% 
  fill_(colnames(DF), .direction = "up") %>% 
  slice(1)

# Source: local data frame [2 x 7]
# Groups: CNTRY [2]
# 
#    CNTRY     V2     V3     V4     V5     V6     V7
#   <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
# 1    XXX      3      B     33      4      7   Four
# 2  Yemen      1      B      3      4      5    Six
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `coalesce` function from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
coalesce(x,y)
#[1] "Yemen" "1"     "B"     "3"     "4"     "5"     "Six"
```